# Laravel Storage::download from Gmail url not working

Tags: laravel, gmail, laravel-storage

In my Laravel 5.8 application I generate dynamically urls to download documents that are stored under `storage` directory.

I send the generated url via email, so user can click it in order to download the file.

When introducing the received link directly in browser, the generated file is downloaded correctly. However, when clicking it from the gmail mailbox, **a new tab is opened and after a second is closed without downloading the file.**

Routing `web.php` file:

```
Route::get('download/{path}', ['as' => 'downloadStorage', 'uses' => 'AppController@downloadStorage'])
  ->where('path', '.*')->middleware('auth');
```

My controller code:

```
public function downloadStorage($path)
{
    $user = \Auth::user();

    // Here I have some code that verify that user is logged
    // and has permissions to download this file
    $hasPermission = true;

    if ($hasPermission) {
        return Storage::download($path);  // <-- THIS LINE IS REACHED CORRECTLY
    } else {
        return abort(403);
    }
}
```

Any idea how can I solve this problem?

My guess is that it has to do with fact that the new tab is closed (due to `return`) before the file is served to browser, but I don't manage to find any solution.

Comment: have you tried  return response()->download(storage_path("file path"));

Comment: make sure pop-up feature not blocked

Comment: @JohnLobo, exactly the same behavior

Comment: Does it work in postman?

Comment: @WaleedMuaz, I tried to enable Pop-ups from [Chrome site-settings](chrome://settings/content/popups) but it doesn't solve my problem. Anyway, I am looking for a solution that will not demand user changing his local settings.

Comment: Yes @onlineThomas. I had to disable logging, but even though it still does not work from gmail.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why exactly app fails to serve file for downloading, however I found the following solution:

Instead of serving file for downliading:

```
return Storage::download($path);
```

I return it so it is opened in a new tab:

```
return \Response::file(Storage::path($path));
```